# Problem configuring Windsor container based on Vendor

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm fairly familiar with the whole concept of IoC/DI, but I've never implemented a solution before. This is my first time, so please feel free to give me a push in the right direction if you deem it necessary.

I've got multiple classes that implement the same Interface(`IMyCustomFileReader`). I need to use one of these instances based on some *Vendor* information in my application. If the Vendor is **Vendor1** I would like the IoC container to give me `Vendor1FlatFileReader` and `DummyClass1` when I request an instance of `IMyCustomFileReader` and `IDummyInterface` respectively.

Similarly I would like the container to return instances of `XMLFileReader` and `DummyClass2` when the Vendor is **Vendor2**.

I think (and let me know when I'm wrong) that I can use it using *ChildContainers*. At the moment my xml looks like this:

```
<components>
  <component id="Vendor1"
             service="SomeAssembly.IMyCustomFileReader, SomeAssembly"
             type="SomeAssembly.Vendor1.Vendor1FlatFileReader, SomeAssembly.Vendor1">
  </component>
  <component id="Vendor1"
             service="SomeAssembly.IDummyInterface, SomeAssembly"
             type="SomeAssembly.DummyClass1, SomeAssembly">
  </component>

  <component id="Vendor2"
             service="SomeAssembly.IMyCustomFileReader, SomeAssembly"
             type="SomeAssembly.XMLFileReader, SomeAssembly">
  </component>
  <component id="Vendor2"
             service="SomeAssembly.IDummyInterface, SomeAssembly"
             type="SomeAssembly.DummyClass2, SomeAssembly">
  </component>
</components>
```

This configuration is erroneous as I cannot have multiple components with the same *id* element - Not even when the Interfaces are different like in the above example. I was hoping I could do something like `Container.Resolve<IMyCustomFileReader>("Vendor1")`, then when an instance of `IMyCustomFileReader` is requested and the `key` value is **Vendor1** I would get back an instance of `Vendor1FlatFileReader`.

I get a `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException` when I try to do it this way.

Something else I think might work is the concept of ChildContainers, but how would I go about configuring those in xml?

Also, I would prefer not to give my components names like `Vendor1_IMyCustomFileReader` and `Vendor2_IMyCustomFileReader`. I would also prefer to have only 1 configuration file and not separate ones for each Vendor (if possible). Has anyone else encountered a similar problem before? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, component ids must be unique. I wouldn't recommend child containers unless you really know what you're doing. In this case, it looks like you're trying to do some sort of multi-tenancy, so I recommend taking a look at [handler selectors](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Handler-Selectors.ashx), this will let you select the appropriate component based on the "vendor" without resorting to service location (if you do container.Resolve() in application-level code, you already lost).

Comment: +1 Very cool feature -- I hadn't seen that one yet.  I'm already coming up with use cases for it...

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to use the [fluent registration API](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Fluent-Registration-API.ashx)?  If so, you could decide which components to register at runtime based on the "vendor" (the registrations for each vendor could live in a separate [IWindsorInstaller](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx) implementation).  This solution assumes you know which "vendor" to use at start-up and that the "vendor" will not change throughout the lifetime of the application (I'm guessing that is a valid assumption based on how you stated the question).  You could take a similar approach with XML configuration, but you would need to separate the configuration for each vendor into separate config files, and you say you are opposed to that -- could you clarify why?

Please comment and let me know if you think that the fluent API approach could work, and I'd be happy to post an example.

Comment: No, fluent registration's not an option as my project don't know of the other projects that implement the interfaces.